# Раздельно или дефис?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, раздельно-дефис, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Как правильно: *Привет, друзья(-)любители космоса*? Мне кажется не очень верным писать через дефис, честно говоря. По сути, *любители космоса* — это словосочетание, по-сути, это вторая часть слова *друзья* (не знаю, правильно ли я сказал). Можно задать вопрос: *Любители (чего?) космоса*. А если написать через дефис, *друзья-любители* станет одним словом и вопрос к *космоса* уже не задастся так просто. А если приставка СУПЕР-: *Супер()любители космоса*? Конкретно эти предложения мне навряд ли пигодятся, мне на будущее, чтоб в других подобных примерах не делать ошибки. Спасибо!

Comment: Дефис не нужен ни для каких любителей, в том числе для СУПЕР. (Если вас особенно интересует именно ЭТА приставка.)  Напишите так:  Привет, друзья, любители космоса!

Comment: Если уж очень хочется поставить тире и сделать увеличенную  паузу, то надо так (без обращения): Привет  друзьЯм – любителям кОсмоса. А иначе получаются две РАЗНЫЕ паузы в предложении из четырех слов. Как прочитать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда определяемое слово и приложение равноправны, как в сочетаниях: офицер-ракетчик, художник-самоучка, соседка-педагог, то ставится дефис, если определяемое слово и приложение состоят из одного слова; а если определяемое слово или приложение состоит из двух и более слов, как в сочетаниях: старшего лейтенанта – артиллериста, участников войны – инвалидов, у научного сотрудника – космонавта, то ставится тире. [Ссылка на правило (пункт 1).](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp154.php)

В итоге будет правильно так: Привет, друзья – любители космоса.